# jqGrid with multiselect:true and reloadGrid double checkbox column

Tags: jqgrid, multi-select

The column for multiselect is saved in the grid param and when I reload the grid using a saved state(`getGridParam`) I get a double column for selection that messes up my column order.

My grid before I load param
[image: before]

After
[image: after]

here is the code :

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    url:'jqgrid/server.php?q=2',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['a','UID','Phone', 'Message', 'created','replyed'],
    colModel:[
          {name:'action',index:'action', width:55,search:false,'sortable':false},
        {name:'id',index:'uid', width:55},
        {name:'phone_number',index:'phone_number', width:90,'editable':true},
        {name:'message',index:'message', width:500,'editable':true},
        {name:'created',index:'created', width:80, align:"right",'editable':true,stype:'select',edittype:"select",editoptions: {value:"Yes:Yes;No:No"}},
        {name:'replyed',index:'replyed', width:80, align:"right",'editable':true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"Yes:No"}},        
    ],
    rowNum:50,
    toolbar: true,
    height: '100%',
    width: 800,
    rowList:[10,20,50,100,300,1000],
    pager: '#pager2',
    sortname: 'uid',
    sortable:true,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",  
    caption:"Pilote",
    gridview : true,
    multiselect: true,
});


function saveStateGrid(){
     state = $('#list2').getGridParam();
     localStorage.setItem("gridState", JSON.stringify(state));
}
function loadStateGrid(){
    state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gridState'));
    jQuery("#list2").GridUnload("#list2");
    //state.multiselect = false;
    $('#list2').jqGrid(state);
    $('#list2').trigger('reloadGrid');
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('gridState'));`? It may be slightly different from what you are expecting.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply.

My problem comes from that colModel and colNames keep the checkbox column.

I solv my problem by remove the column from colModel and colNames before saving